# Taking root from absolute expression

Tags: calculus, inequality, absolute-value, radicals

Why is the following true? (Where all terms are positive)

$$|x-y| < \epsilon^2 \implies |\sqrt x - \sqrt y| < \epsilon$$

Comment: Because $|\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{y}| \ge |\sqrt{x} - \sqrt{y}|$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align}
|\sqrt{x} - \sqrt{y}| =
\frac{|x - y|}{|\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{y}|} \le \frac{|x - y|}{|\sqrt{x} - \sqrt{y}|}
< \frac{\epsilon^2}{|\sqrt{x} - \sqrt{y}|}
\end{align}

Comment: Nice. Thank you @Tunococ

Comment: @idm Sorry. I don't follow.

Comment: @idm That seems right. I'm not sure how that is used?

Comment: @Tunococ: what do you mean ? Your proff is right only if $|\sqrt x-\sqrt y|\geq 1$ but not if $|\sqrt x-\sqrt y|<1$. Do you understand why ?

Comment: @idm I don't think I understand why.

Comment: because $\varepsilon^2>\varepsilon$, then your proof work only for the case where $|\sqrt x-\sqrt y|>1$ and $\varepsilon<1$.

Comment: @idm I really don't follow your argument. Please tell me which step is wrong. And why are you saying that $\varepsilon^2 > \varepsilon$?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16530/discussion-between-tunococ-and-idm).

Comment: I can't chat. Well, your inequality is correct, but how do you conclude that $|\sqrt x-\sqrt y|<\varepsilon$ ? This is my question.

Comment: @idm I showed all my steps except the last (which is multiplying by $|\sqrt{x} - \sqrt{y}|$ and taking the square root). I wonder which step is questionable.

Comment: @idm Oh. You didn't see that last step I skipped, did you?

Comment: @Tunococ: I apologize, I'm sincerely sorry I indeed didn't see the last step... Your proof is really really good. I'm so sorry for these mistakes. I gave you a downvote before and I can't erase it and upvote for your great proof. I hope it's fine for you and all my excuses. I erase all my previously comment to not confuse anyone.

Comment: @idm Don't worry. I completely understand. This kind of thing happens every once in a while :)

Answer (score 1):

An other proof would be:

If $0\leq y\leq x\leq$, 
$$\left|\sqrt x-\sqrt y\right|^2=\left(\sqrt x-\sqrt y\right)^2=x-2\sqrt x\sqrt y+y\leq x-2y+y=x-y=|x-y|,$$

The proof for $0\leq x\leq y$ is the same. Then for all $x,y\geq 0$, 
$$\left|\sqrt x-\sqrt y\right|\leq \sqrt{|x-y|}$$

and so, $$|x-y|<\varepsilon^2\implies \left|\sqrt x-\sqrt y\right|<\varepsilon$$

Q.E.D.